# Forward declaration of derived class

Tags: c++, class, declaration

I have some code like that:

```
class Class1 {
    // some code here

    Class2 inverse() {
        // some code here
    }
};

class Class2 : public Class1 {
    // some code here
};
```

And I got an error that `Class2` is unknown in function `inverse`. Can I declare that class and how?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can forward declare `Class2` before `Class1`. And then you'll have to separate your `inverse` function declaration from definition. So you should *define* its after Class2 is defined:

```
class Class2;
class Class1 {
// some code here

Class2 inverse();
};

class Class2: public Class1 {
// some code here
};

Class2 Class1::inverse()
{
    return Class2();
}
```

But, honestly, it is *bad* design.

Comment: Thanks, it works. I know that it is bad design((( Professor at university give me such task

Answer (score 0):

`Class2` is not defined when you reach `Class2 inverse()` so even forward declaring would not completely solve that issue. However you can do two things. Either return a pointer or a reference to `Class2`

```
class Class2;
^^^^^^^^^^^^
class Class1 {    
    Class2& inverse() {
    //   ^^^ or possibly Class2*
       // 
    }
};

class Class2: public Class1 {
}
```

---

Or defined `inverse` after `Class2` have been completely defined

```
class Class2;
class Class1 {
   Class2 inverse(); 
};

class Class2: public Class1 {
   // 
}

Class2 Class1::inverse() {
    // 
}
```

---

I would go with the second option if possible.